# How to save react application as html?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to save react application(right-click save as HTML) as HTML, everything works great but events(click, toggle) are not working. Any reason why?

Comment: That's because you can't do that, React applications are reactive, their HTML is generated based on events. When you save a site from your browser you download the current state of the page.

Comment: please share your code via sandbox or something like platform that it will more make sense to us

Comment: You need to also save the js file

Comment: @AdrianPascu - I tried but no help

Comment: But what is it that you are trying to achieve?